# Split Bus electrical panel

Tags: electrical

Looking for a single phase **split bus load center** No main required , and 100 amp is plenty big.
about 14 to 24 circuits total is large enough (12+- on each)
don't have room for a sub panel so I need the split bus to house the inverter circuits.
Anyone know where I could find on of these

Comment: Flagged for closure because SE is not meant for product recommendations.

Comment: You want to go a lot larger than that.  Everybody says "so-and-so is large enough" when clutching their wallet at the supplier... Different story when they're trying to add circuits for e 240V table saw and the dust collector... Or the wife realizes it's feasible to have more than 2 circuits in the kitchen and now you're trying to find GFCI tandems.   10 more spaces is about $3 when buying the panel.  Or $1000 later.  I would go 42-space myself.

Comment: Thanks HariAfter reading your response and re-reading my question,, I have realized I failed to mention I am replacing an existing in our "houseboat" and only have room for a panel 14.5 wide by 18" tall with a "split bus"

Comment: need 10 circuits on top bus

Comment: 8 circuits on bottom bus

Comment: @DeWayneAkins Well why didn't you say so LOL!  Marine panels are completely different critters.  Head off to your chandlery and they'll have answers for you.

Comment: Could you put two separate panels stacked vertically with one feeding the other, or some similar arrangement? This would be immediately clear (with some nicely labeled dead fronts) to anyone (reasonably intelligent) working on. I am fairly certain a cursory search will reveal a nice pair of panels that are <9" tall each.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't put that in a new structure anyhow

While the rule of six (230.71) is not a dead letter (there are still cases in new construction where a panel lacking a main disconnect can be installed), the "split bus" type panels you speak of are no longer Code, as they violate 408.36, Exception 1:

> **408.36 Overcurrent Protection.** In addition to the requirement of 408.30, a panelboard shall be protected by an
>   overcurrent protective device having a rating not greater
>   than that of the panelboard. This overcurrent protective device shall be located within or at any point on the supply
>   side of the panelboard.
>
> *Exception No.1: Individual protection shall not be required for a panelboard used as service equipment with
>   multiple disconnecting means in accordance with 230.71.
>   In panelboards protected by three or more main circuit
>   breakers or sets of fuses, the circuit breakers or sets of
>   fuses shall not supply a second bus structure within the
>   same panelboard assembly.*

### But, marine panelboards are totally different beasts

Marine electrical gear is a different creature from the household stuff you were initially thinking of, and a bit beyond the scope of this site in some cases.  I'd talk with a specialist familiar with the subtle hazards AC on a boat poses if I were in your shoes -- electric shock drowning hazards are *brutal*.

Answer (score 0):

### An antique shop

Split-bus panels are obsolete, kinda dangerous, and a rich environment for code violations.  They're obsolete because the "rule of six" has gone by the wayside.  It was hopeless; homeowners and handymen not knowing any better would routinely slap a single or even tandem in the top 12 spaces, violating the rule of six.   They're dangerous because consumers don't know how to de-energize them.  How do you turn off power when there's no main breaker?  "Turn off all the breakers in the top 12 spaces" is insanely non-intuitive regardless of labeling.

The reason to do them *was* cost -- split bus panels were half the price because big main breakers were expensive.  Not anymore.  The rate these panels caused trouble was not worth it.

I do note its potential value for switching generators; put the interlocked shoreside and generator breakers in the top 4 spaces of the lower area.  The problem is you're then putting all non-generator loads in the top 12 spaces, and on a house, that will take a lot of cram, and you'll inevitably violate the rule of six.  It might work if you had a main breaker outside as part of the meter pan or shore service, and this was already a subpanel.

But no-one will sell you a new one.  So you will need to scrounge it.

Comment: It's actually against Code to *install* a split bus panel (230.71 hasn't changed, but they now violate the conditions on 408.36 ex.1 which is 230.71's 'other half').

Comment: Thanks for your input Harper. I understand the issues with these panels and I do have a main shore/generator disconnect ahead of the this panel

Comment: If that's handled, I would go with a normal panel.  The cost motivation.no longer exists.